# how to override Map variable values defined on module level on terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

Ex: I have created custom module in terraform

```
main.tf
resource "xyz" "abc" {
 name = var.settings[name]
 type = var.settings[type]
}

variable.tf
variable "settings" {
 type = map(any)
 description = "Default variables"
  default = {
    name  = "test"
    type = "instance"
}
```

I am accessing this module and want to override the default values while accessing module

```
module "xyz" {

source ="../../xyz"
name = "google"    // want to override this default value 
type = "cloud"     //want to override this default value 
}
```

please help how to override the map variable defined on module level

Comment: It is unclear whether the config provided at the beginning of the question is part of the root module config, or the declared module `xyz` config. Could you please clarify?

Comment: yes config and default vars provided on module level as well and when i sourcing this module to use I want to override those variable

Answer (score 2):

You pass it in as a map as well, i.e.:

```
module "xyz" {
  source ="../../xyz"
  settings = {
    name = "google"
    type = "cloud"
  }
}
```

---

Note that your `main.tf` in the module is missing `""`:

```
resource "xyz" "abc" {
  name = var.settings["name"]
  type = var.settings["type"]
}
```

And your `variables.tf` in the module is missing a closing `}`:

```
variable "settings" {
  type = map(any)
  description = "Default variables"
  default = {
    name = "test"
    type = "instance"
  }
}
```